# Nodebeats -> MongoDB connection using mongodb+srv and not using admin db still throwing unauthorised error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

This is the error I am getting on **"npm start"** on the root directory

{
ok: 0,
errmsg: '(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { listIndexes: "MailService", cursor: {  }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: {1597768215 1}, signature: { hash: {0 [177 157 37 8 5 144 139 236 187 152 178 244 217 101 9 101 145 52 191 21]}, keyId: 6831855223338696704.000000 } }, lsid: { id: {4 [228 34 228 12 148 119 79 77 190 155 105 183 147 221 25 233]} } }',
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError'
}

The url to connect "mongodb+srv://subhampatel29:@<my_domain_name>/nodebeatsdb?retryWrites=true"

The DB I am using is named **nodebeatsdb** and not **admin**.

Comment: You apparently are trying to list indexes on admin db which your user isn't allowed to do. Use a named database for your application rather than admin.

Comment: That is what I am not able to get. I haven't given the path to admin db anywhere but still it tries to operate on that DB. The DB is am using is named "nodebeatsdb".

Comment: admin is the default database, you can have a misconfigured client somewhere.

Comment: I don't know why this is failing! I am not able to find the root cause.

Comment: Start removing code not relevant to the problem. You can connect to MongoDB and perform a query in about 10 lines. Once you have your code down to 10 lines or so add it to the question.